# How to return different views in UITableView Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a table view with one section, which is populated from an array holding 4 objects. 
I would like to load a textfield in the last row, but I don't know how to return two different cells in `cellForRowAt indexPath: _)`. I can create 2 prototype cells, give them different identifiers, but If I use `if else`, only one cell will be returned.

```
  var options = [
    Item(name:"Doorman",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Lockbox",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Hidden-Key",selected: false),
    Item(name:"Other",selected: false)
 ]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return options.count
}   

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


 // configure the cell
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell     {
        var cell: UITableViewCell
      if indexPath.row <= 4 {
     cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row].name
        return cell!
        } else {
      cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textField")
        return cell!

 }
```

This is what I am trying to achieve. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is ok, you're using two different identifiers, but I also see that you just have 4 items in **options** array. Then inside **cellForRowAt**, you have

```
if indexPath.row <= 4 {
```

So it will never enter to the **else**. You'd need to change it to:

```
if indexPath.row < 3 {
```

Comment: This is essentially correct, but I believe you have to change the condition to < 3 since row is 0-based :)

Comment: @Fahim you're right, I updated the answer, thank you

Comment: @Fahim I have created a UITableViewCell class in a .swift file for the textField and in that class I connected the textField from IB. In a second file I have a `UIViewController:UITableViewcontroller`, how can i reference the textField from the previous class here so that I can check if text is entered?

Comment: @bibscy This is going to take a bit of explanation - and the comment field is not long enough for me to do that. So why not mark carlos21's answer as "correct" so that he gets credit and then ask a new question? I will answer that to show you how you can do what you want ...

Comment: @bibscy Will take a look as soon as I finish breakfast :) Somebody else might beat me to that though ... But either way, you'll get your answer.